# How to get the "title" from the <span>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get the title "Product Manager" from the code below?

```html
<div class="new_job_name" data-v-99ef4628="">
    <span data-v-99ef4628="">Product Manager</span>
</div>
```

If the title was in the `<div class= "new_job_name">`, I can get it using the code below:

```
soup.find(class_="new_job_name").attrs["title"]
```

Now I have no idea how to get the "title" within the `<span>` under the `<div class>`.

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then you should mark the question that best helped you as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just find the `span` inside the `div` with class `new_job_name`

```
soup.find(class_="new_job_name").find('span').text
```

Note: I have framed this answer based on your HTML, if there are multiple `div` with class `new_job_name` then you need to loop through the array

Comment: The schema posted by OP does not have the title attribute, so you are assuming the schema,

Comment: Sorry, nope you're right. Just mislead by OP's use of `.attr`.